# What attributes would a human sized ant require in order to exist, in respect to biology as well as physics?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

I have done some research on this topic and I have found two things that majorly hinder simply making a large ant:

They would asphyxiate due to their way of respiration and their exoskeleton would break, causing their internal organs to spill.

The square cube law.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As our [help] states, questions which contains already the answer are not a good fit here, and this seems the case. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to ask what attributes the race will need.

Comment: And you also listed what are the main problems. I don't see the problem to be solved.

Comment: Please concentrate on one specific question at a time. Currently you ask "what all must change?". A better fit would be presenting your current thought like "I think I could give them proper lungs, but I don't know how thick and strong their exoskeleton needs to be". Based on that, ask one specific question with a limited scope like "Could the exoskeleton of an ant be adapted to not break at human size and still enable the ant to move?" If you already found the mayor problem and cannot do the calculations, clarify that as well so users know what you already figured out and can help you better.

Comment: How about making it the equivalent of a nanobot swarm?  That at least gets rid of the necessity for an internal circulation system to distribute oxygen, nutrition, etc.

Comment: Okay, so you've done some research, which is **a really good thing!** ...so, what's the problem you're trying to solve? Please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] and find out [what this forum is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about).  As written, your inquiry is just too nebulous and unformed. ***All Stack Exchange forums*** require that you ask a single, focussed question. Fishing expeditions, open ended questions, questions that ask for lists --- those can be taken to Reddit.

Comment: @Elmy Thanks for the sample question :) I'll ask that one then.